# Problem in redirecting site visitor to mobile.html

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, mobile

I have built a basic gaming site for learning and want the user to be directed to index.html if the user uses a desktop and to mobile.html if the user is on a tablet or mobile when visiting the site.

I have tried to use the following script for redirecting...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">
    if (screen.width <= 699) {
        document.location = "mobile.html";
    }
</script>
```

(script.js contains more js code that the site uses)

... but it does not redirect when visiting the site from my Iphone.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

And please let me know if my question is to vage, I am still new here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A bit off-topic, but you need to look into "responsive design".

Comment: Thank you. Will take course this weekend @PM77-1.

Answer (score -1):

I've never tried to put code in a script block with a src attribute.

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" />
<script>
    if (screen.width <= 699) {
        document.location = "mobile.html";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: That won't work. Script elements require end tags.